# Get rows of parents without children

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

| UID | CHILD_UID |
| --- | --- |
| a | {} |
| b | {} |
| c | {a} |

`UID` is a `VARCHAR` and `CHILD_UID` is a `VARCHAR[]`. I need a query that returns b,c. I mean a list of parents without children, checking that the `uid` is not in any of the `child_uid` rows.

- a is not a parent, is a child of c.
- b is a parent.
- c is a parent.

I have tried this but with no results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE NOT uid = ANY(SELECT child_uid FROM table);
```

In words, get the items that its `uid` is not in the `child_uid` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`child_uid` is an array, so it should be converted to a list of childs (using `UNNEST`)

```sql
SELECT * FROM table 
   WHERE NOT uid = ANY(SELECT unnest(child_uid) FROM table);
```